# Authentication w/ Omniauth (No Devise) - How to Check is Signed In in Routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I'm using only omniauth-oauth2 for authentication (No Devise).  I would like to define different roots for  users who are signed in and are not, to include a secure dashboard.  I have a current_user method in my Application Controller, but I can't seem to access it in my routes. Does anyone have any recommendations as to how I can best do this?

**Application Controller:**

```
helper_method :current_user

private

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
```

**This does not work:**

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do


 if :current_user
   root :to => "home#show"
 else
   root :to => "home#index"
 end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **routes.rb** file, just specify the **constraint** for routing based on condition.

```
root :to => 'home#show', :constraints => lambda{|req| !req.session[:user_id].blank?}
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Hope this will useful as you are storing the **user_id** in the session, this will work